# Debug Mode Broken in Winter 2021

Tags: lightning-web-components

With the advent of Winter 2021, Debug Mode appears to be broken in orgs.  A page layout that renders fine for a user with Debug Mode unchecked receives the following error when Debug Mode is checked:

"Looks like there's a problem.
Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details."

Is anyone else experiencing this nonsense?  Any ideas?  Also there are NO errors in the console when the page is rendering and shows this error above....

Thanks.

Comment: whats the error ID?

Comment: No error Id, Mohith.

Comment: This is broken for me with my LWC component when use wire methods.  Example     @wire(getProfileData) profiles;  If I comment that out, my page loads.